# MongoDB aggregation to group dynamic keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working on an aggregation of counts of the value of a variable number of bar rows like in this data structure :

```
> db.data.find()
{ "_id" : "foo1", "1" : { "bar" : 6 }, "0" : { "bar" : 11 }, "3" : { "bar" : 8 }, "2" : { "bar" : 0 }, "5" : { "bar" : 8 }, "4" : { "bar" : 19 }, "6" : { "bar" : 8 } }
{ "_id" : "foo2", "1" : { "bar" : 18 }, "0" : { "bar" : 3 }, "3" : { "bar" : 19 }, "2" : { "bar" : 0 }, "5" : { "bar" : 13 }, "4" : { "bar" : 17 }, "7" : { "bar" : 8 }, "6" : { "bar" : 8 }, "8" : { "bar" : 8 } }
{ "_id" : "foo3", "1" : { "bar" : 0 }, "0" : { "bar" : 2 }, "3" : { "bar" : 18 }, "2" : { "bar" : 2 }, "4" : { "bar" : 12 } }
```

I'm able to do this individually, but is it possible to do this across the whole data set? Output format isn't really import to me, but here's an idea:

**Desired Output :**

```
bar0: 16
bar1: 24
bar2: 2
bar3: 45
bar4: 48
bar5: 21
bar6: 16
bar7: 8
bar8: 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using MongoDB's [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) framework :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Remove not needed fields, which will lessen size of doc */
    { $project: { _id: 0 } },
    /** As you've dynamic field names - convert each field in doc into {k:...,v:...} & entire doc is pushed into array field `data` */
    {
      $project: { data: {  $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$data"
    },
    /** group to bring same 'k' values together & sum-up bar value */
    {
      $group: { _id: "$data.k", bar: { $sum: "$data.v.bar" } }
    },
    /** Can be Optional, Project needed fields `data` will be an object */
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        data: { $arrayToObject: [ [ { "k": { $concat: [ "bar", "$_id" ] }, "v": "$bar" } ] ] } } 
    },
    /** Make `data` field as new root for doc */
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$data"
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PasJ7diT5D1)

**Note :** Try not to have dynamic key names - Which will lead to many issues on reads, Also stages after `$group` are optional in above query they're there to get the output look like in desired format, better to test till `$group` stage & check if it's ok for your need.

Comment: in the first $project - you are selecting what you want to remove from fields - is it possible to specify a "tree" you want to include?  For example:
foo.baz.bar

Comment: @elofland : Yes you can do that something like `foo.baz.bar : 1` but it all depends on how data looks like for `foo.baz.bar`..

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific - can't expect you to read my mind...   I was thinking foo.baz.bar would be an object or document

Comment: @elofland : In that case you can do ‘foo.baz.bar : 1’ in case if it didn’t work please post sample data and required o/p, myself or someone will help you..

Comment: finally made it work with my real data and realized I was (partially) asking the wrong question...  Looks like I need a count of the records with each bar value - for example:
bar8: 6

Comment: looks like just using { sum:1} adds the occurrences of baz.data.X.bar, but not the aggregation on the values of baz.data.X.bar - i.e. there are two  occurences where baz.data.X.bar = 3

Comment: @elofland : `{$sum:1}` in `$group` gives you count of docs but doesn't sum-up values you need to do `{$sum : '$baz.data.X.bar'}` not sure what't happening with your query right now but I guess this might be what you're looking for..

Comment: this query gives me a sum.of the values of bar for each baz.data.X.bar:
> db.data.aggregate([ { $project: { _id: 0, "baz.data": 1 } }, { $project: { data: {  $objectToArray: "$baz.data" } } }, { $unwind: "$data" },{ $group: { _id: "$data.k", bar: { $sum: "$data.v.bar" } } }, { $project: { _id: 0, data: { $arrayToObject: [ [ { "k": { $concat: [ "bar", "$_id" ] }, "v": "$bar" } ] ] } } }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } } ])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212694/discussion-between-elofland-and-whoami).

Comment: > db.data.aggregate([ { $project: { _id: 0, "baz.data": 1 } }, { $project: { data: {  $objectToArray: "$baz.data" } } }, { $unwind: "$data" },{ $group: { _id: "$data.v.bar", bar:{"$first":"$data.v.bar"}, count: { $sum:1 } } }, { $project: { _id: 0, data: { $arrayToObject: [ [ { "k": { $concat: [ "bar", { "$toString": "$bar" } ] }, "v": "$count" } ] ] } } }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } } ])
{ "bar9" : 1 }
{ "bar1" : 1 }
{ "bar15" : 3 }
{ "bar6" : 1 }
{ "bar4" : 1 }
{ "bar16" : 1 }
{ "bar7" : 1 }
{ "bar3" : 2 }
{ "bar18" : 1 }
{ "bar12" : 1 }
{ "bar8" : 2 }
{ "bar13" : 1 }